# Increase performance of simple find -exec command

Tags: bash, performance

Say I have a very simple command running in bash:

```
find [folder] -exec ( echo [something manipulated with sed]; cat [small_file]; ) > file
```

where folder contains 6 million small files, e.g.:

```
$ cat smallfile_000000001.txt
123456789012345678901234567890
```

How can I make this faster .. or troubleshoot with top/iostats what is making this process take forever? With 6 million files it takes around 6 hours. In one second around 270 files are processed.

Any tips or analysis to steer me in the right direction will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:** the exact exec is:

```
-exec ./helper.sh {} \; > output.txt
```

where `helper.sh` is:

```
echo -ne "$1 " | sed 's/\.\.\/something\/foo\/bar\/123\///'
cat "$1"
exit 0
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly in the `-exec` predicate?

Comment: How fast is your disk?`How quickly can you just read those 6 million files and throw away the data? That's your baseline. If your processing is dominated by the bare I/O overhead, there isn't really much you can improve, other than getting a faster disk (or reduce the amount of data).

Comment: exec added to the question above.

Comment: @tripleee: i don't know the disk speed. I suspect they are mechanical though. how would you measure that? would something like find [folder] -exec cat to dev/null do it?

Comment: I think the problem is not so much opening the vast amount of small files, but created separated processes (by what comes after `-exec`) for each file. I would rewrite the whole script in a programming language which offers you convenient methods for traversing a directory tree and do string manipulations, all in one process. For instance, Ruby or Perl would suit well for this type of problem (as would do many others).

Comment: You are probably very near the maximum speed of the I/O that your disk can provide.  Just `time find folder -exec cat {} + >/dev/null` would indicate how long the baseline takes (but if you are nervous about performance, probably run it on a smaller set of files).

Comment: Changing `helper` so it loops over files so that you can use `-exec helper {} +` instead of `-exec helper {} \;` would reduce the processing overhead, but it's probably not going to result in any savings in time (though efficiency should improve somewhat).

Comment: I'm going to run time find folder -exec cat {} + >/dev/null in about 2-3 hours when the current process finishes. Will post the result. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `awk` instead of your `helper.sh` as follows: `find [folder] -exec awk 'FNR == 1 {sub(/\.\.\/something\/foo\/bar\/123\//, "", FILENAME); print FILENAME} 1' {} + > output.txt`. This will be much faster as it will not launch a separate `sed` and `cat` for each file: only one `awk` for a bunch of files. Try it on a smaller subset of files (e.g., 1000 or 10000 files) to check that the speed is really improved.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, little lost on your awk command. i need to have one line which says FILENAME_with_sub <space> content_of_file ... how to achieve it? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `-n` switch to echo; so your files all consist of one single line? in this case it's even easier: `find [folder] -exec awk '{sub(/\.\.\/something\/foo\/bar\/123\//, "", FILENAME); print FILENAME, $0}' {} + > output.txt`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you were right, changing the "exec" like gniourf suggested increased speed 8x! post an answer so i can give you credit! Thanks!!

Comment: @user1934428 you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spawning a script, `sed` and `cat` for *each* file found. You'll get good speed improvement by using another design: use the `-exec ... +` construct with `awk` as follows:

```
find [folder] -exec awk '{sub(/\.\.\/something\/foo\/bar\/123\//, "", FILENAME); print FILENAME, $0}' {} + > output.txt
```

This will launch a unique `awk` for a bunch of files.